# Fill out online form

Tags: python-3.x, https, web-crawler

I'm trying to fill out the form located at `https://idp.ncedcloud.org/idp/AuthnEngine#/authn` with a username and password. I want to know if went through successfully or not. I tried it ith python2, but I couldn't get it to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib
import urllib2

name =  "username"
name2 = "password"
data = { 
        "description" : name, 
        "ember501": name2
       }   

encoded_data = urllib.urlencode(data)
content = urllib2.urlopen("https://idp.ncedcloud.org/idp/AuthnEngine#/authn",
        encoded_data) 
print(content)
```

error:
It prints the content of the same webpage, and I want it to print the new webpage content.
desired behavior:
python3 solution that goes to the next webpage, or why my code isn't working

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? :(

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic example of posting data to a webpage like this using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) library. I would suggest using session, so that your login info is saved for any following requests:

```
import requests

url = "http://example.com"

name =  "username"
name2 = "password"
data = { 
    "description" : name, 
    "ember501": name2
}   

s = requests.Session()

# If it supports basic auth you could just do 
# s.auth(username, password) here before a request 

req = s.post(url, data=data)

print(req.text)
```

Should then be able to do following requests with the `s` session object