# Filling forms automatically with python for a website

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to find a way to fill automatically a form for a website using urllib. The website is a french buy and sell website : www.kijiji.ca 
Basically, my brother has a bike business and I'm trying to help him list the bikes automatically through his database.
Right now I know I need to use `urllib` and maybe the `request` module, but every example I stumble on is outdated (they use python 2).
Here is the listing platform : 
https://www.kijiji.ca/p-admarkt-post-ad.html?categoryId=648

The examples I stumble on are a bit like this one :

```
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://whatever.foo/form.html'
form_data = {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2'}
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
```

There's no urllib2 in python 3 and I have no clue how to do this on my own...
Do you guys have some references or guidance for me?
Thank you!

Comment: Check this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39863285/3194722

Comment: You can read [this post about urllib in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792650/python3-error-import-error-no-module-name-urllib2)

Comment: you should be using `Requests` or Selenium.